# How to count number of records using AJAX(without jQuery) and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am a beginner programmer and I would like to count the number of records in a table. I have seen plenty of extracts of codes but I cant seem to piece them together to transfer the PHP result to my javascript codes. Here are the codes I have ended up with :

showscan.php

```
<php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
try{
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "bencoolen");

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM discountcode";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    echo mysql_num_rows($result);

    $conn->close();
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "error";

}
?>
```

index.html

```
<head>
<!-- The policy below is cancelled out so the project can run on my android device's version -->    
<!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">-->
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.datepicker.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script id="mobile-datepicker" src="js/jquery.mobile.datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="barcodescanner.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="common.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showscan(){
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = serverURL() + "/showscan.php";
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                //The alert below was alerted                           
                alert("readystate and status OK");
                document.getElementById("noscan").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;

                //The alert below was not alerted
                alert(document.getElementById("noscan").innerHTML);             
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send(); 
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
        <div data-role="content" class="ui-content" id="loginsection">
            <form name="LoginForm">
                <div class="ui-grid-a">
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <input id="noscan" type="text" class="input-text" placeholder="Number of scans"/>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
     </div>
</body>
```

*'document.getElementById("noscan").innerHTML'* was not getting alerted and the field containing *'document.getElementById("noscan").innerHTML'* stated below html file was also blank after the function ran. These codes were part of my programming notes after I removed all json_encoding, because I was not sure what it does and to follow examples better. I do have jQuery installed but jQuery Ajax is a little too overwhelming for me and I can visualise making an Ajax call without jQuery better.

Question: How to I make it so that the count(*) value from PHP gets transfered over to my javascript code?
In what situations will I have to encode my results with JSON before sending them over?

Thanks!

Comment: and your html code?

Comment: alright added most of the stuff in, only left out unrelated fields like login and password!

Comment: Try using `value` instead of `innerHTML`, like: `document.getElementById("noscan").value = xmlHttp.responseText;`

Comment: @ImClarky you're right ! thank you for your time lookin through !! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright you have some typos & some errors in your code:

**TYPOS**
Your `<php` tag in your `showscan.php` => `<?php`

`xmlHttp` in the line `document.getElementById("noscan").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;` of javascript function `showscan()` should be `xmlhttp`. (small h) since **JavaScript** is a **case-sensitive** language.

**Errors** 
**javascript showscan()**
`noscan` in   `document.getElementById("noscan").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;` is a `text input` and input text does not have property `innerHTML`

**showscan.php**

`mysql_num_rows;` in `echo mysql_num_rows($result);` should be `mysqli_num_rows;` notice the difference? `mysql` & `mysqli`

**Suggesstion**

`serverURL()` in `var url = serverURL() + "/showscan.php";` if you have this `showscan.php` page in the same folder then just write `showscan.php`.

By the looks of your `HTML` code, I don't see anything calling your function `showscan()`. Therefore, either you can call it on `body` load `<body onload="showscan();">` or insert a `<button>` and call it with `onclick` attribute `<button  type="button" onclick="showscan();">submit</button>`

**NOW TRY THIS CODE**

**showscan.php**

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    error_reporting(E_ERROR);
    try{
        $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "bencoolen");
        $query = "SELECT * FROM discountcode";
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $conn->close();
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        echo "error";
    }
?>
```

**Javascript Function showscan()**

```
function showscan(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "showscan.php";
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            //The alert below was alerted                           
            alert("readystate and status OK");
            document.getElementById("noscan").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
            //The alert below was not alerted
            alert(document.getElementById("noscan").value);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

Comment: Yep yep !!! this is it! Thank you for taking me step by step towards the answer and taking your time out looking through and typing out these codes !

Comment: Happy to help and getting help :)

Comment: also, my sql query is wrong if i want to use mysqli_num_rows($result) ;_; so I'll edit it the statement to 'select *' instead of 'select count()'